# MySQL - Copy Database then delete data or new database then insert, between performance

Tags: mysql, performance

i have a database, name: **companydb2017**.
in tables(Examples:)[all type **InnoDB**]

```
stocks
presents
invoices
invoicelines
invoiceamounts
```

i do revolve data.(transfer data).

i have two way binding. first; mysqldump export companydb2017 then mysql import companydb2018. Then; I will delete 2017 data (companydb2018).

```
mysqldump -u root -p companydb2017 > companydb2017.sql

mysql -u root -p companydb2018 < companydb2017.sql

use companydb2018;
delete from invoices where SAVEDATE<'2018-01-01';
```

second way; mysql export structure only companydb2017 then mysql import companydb2018. Then; i will find 2018 data(companydb2017), export and import data(companydb2018).

```
mysqldump -u root -p --no-data companydb2017 > companydb2017_structure.sql
mysql -u root -p companydb2018 < companydb2017_structure.sql

use companydb2017;
"select * from invoices where SAVEDATE>='2018-01-01'" export > 2018_data.sql

mysql -u root -p companydb2018 < 2018_data.sql
```

after the transfer; is there a performance difference between these two ways?
example question: is there difference companydb2018 select query times?

Comment: Why not remove any reference to a year, and just stick with one db? Beyond that, I really think that this question would be better directed at the dba forum

Comment: Test it and you will see.

Comment: @Shadow, i will test. test result some. but, there are people who say it's not the same. I want information from the DB experts.

Comment: @Strawberry because; there is a table min 10 million row; but, it's rarely used.it's used separately every year. Yes, the dba forum seems to be the best option. Thanks.

Comment: By testing you can get factual data, experts can only give you opinions.

Comment: And take a look at proper partitioning